# Wordpress insert image alternative

Tags: wordpress, image, upload

Is it possible to upload an image to a Wordpress post without using the 'Add Media' button and the Insert Media window.

I'm creating a forum type page where people can upload to images to post they create.

The 'Add Media' button and Insert Media window is perfect when clients are adding images to there own sites but I don't want users to this site to be able to create galleries they would like them to just upload images.

Comment: You can't - You only can "hide" the gallery feature with CSS/Javascript.

Comment: Hiding part of the Insert image page should work. I think the css file at wp-includes > css > media-views.min.css looks like it's the css to alter. Does anyone know where this min.css file is referenced in Wordpress. I'd need to change the reference to the non min version before changing it.

Comment: Dont change core files! Use your browsers inspector to find the relevant CSS-Part and override it with `!important`

Comment: Thanks Adrain, that will work for me. I'll just overwrite the current styling